# how to disable an exchange 2007 mailbox from one AD user ID and reconnected it to another AS user ID

Tags: exchange

I have an old AD account that we are deleting. I need to disable his exchange 2007 mailbox from that account and assign it to the new account.

How do I do this?

I tried in exchange management right clicking the mailbox and disabling the account. But it disappears after that. If I disconnect the mailbox it will remove the userID from AD and show the mail box in the disconnected mail boxes bin. From there I can reconnect it to another ID.

I need to be able to disable it without deleting the original user account and just assign it to another user account.

I am sure that I am just missing something stupid. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, when the mailbox is disabled you can only get to it via the console. from there you can reconnect it to another account.

Comment: +1 so the question doesn't show as unanswered and because you came back and updated when you found the answer.